# Connected to WiFi, but connect Ethernet and it quit working

Tags: wireless-networking

When I turned my laptop on the servers, Google or Firefox would not load. my WiFi says it is connected, but I connected the Ethernet into it and it quit loading servers, but it still says the WiFi is on...can not figure out what to do....Laptop with Windows 7 on it works and cell phone works with WiFi, but my laptop with Windows 8 won't.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking. Are you saying that the internet works over Wi-Fi, but not over Ethernet? What kind of router do you have? Have you tried connecting other routers (perhaps at a friends house?).

Answer (score 0):

The BIOS may have a setting that disallows the simultaneous use of both the Cat5 / ethernet and WiFi. We had many HP laptops/TabletPCs that had this feature in the BIOS. Consider it a security feature to not bridge WiFi and a private LAN. Consider it as a way to simplify network management in some cases with a single MAC.

Does the WiFi work again when the ethernet cord is unplugged?